# Let s be a set of five positive integers at most 9. Prove that the sums of the elements in all the non empty subsets of s cannot be distinct.?

Tags: sumset

Let s be the set of five positive integer the maximum of which is at most 9 prove that the sums of the elements in all the non empty subset of as cannot be distinct?

Note:
I know this is similar to another question with 6 elements with max 14.

I saw this in Quora, and it annoys me that my proof is essentially
a backtracking proof to eliminate all the possibilities.

It starts like this:

They have to be distinct or else two 1-element sets have the same sum.

If the largest is 8 then the largest the set can be is 8-7-6-5-4 which sums to 30 but there are 31 possible sets so this can not be.

So 9 is there.
If 8 is there then 1 can’t be.

And so on.

My questions:

(1) If there a more elegant proof?

(2) What is the proper generalization replacing 9 and 5?

They all must be distinct,
so if the max is $n$
and there are $m$ of them
then to force the max to be $n$
we must have
$(n-1)+(n-2)+...(n-m)
\lt 2^m-1
$
or
$mn-\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}
\lt 2^m-1
$
or
$n
\lt \dfrac{2^m-1}{m}+\dfrac{m+1}{2}
$.
For $m=5$ this is
$n \lt \dfrac{31}{5}+3
=9+\dfrac15
$
so
$n \le 9$.

But I don't see how to
elegantly prove
nonexistence.

Comment: Does the fact that it is a *set* of five integers mean that the integers are distinct?  If so, then you should be able to pigeonhole your way home.

Comment: As I wrote, they must be distinct because two equal elements have equal 1-element set sums.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Pigeonhole principle.  You can form $31$ sums in total from the non-empty subsets of the five numbers.  What is the largest such possible sum? What is the smallest?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the sum of your five numbers and the smallest of your five numbers plus $1$ gives you the size of the range your sums can land in.  This can be at most $31$, which is only  attained if your numbers include $6,7,8,9$.

To see this note that size of range of $9,8,7,6,5$ is $35-5+1=31$, and lowering the bottom number does not effect this, but lowering any other number does lower it.

Thus the five numbers must include $6,7,8,9$, as if the range has size less than $31$, then the $31$ sums cannot be distinct.  However $6+9=7+8$ so the sums are not distinct.